# Angel's workspace

Tags: apocalypse-world-2e

I am preparing to play in my first game of Apocalypse World and just wanted to double check one thing. The Angel gets a special workspace that lets them work on people, and it comes with parts of its own, the life support table, the crew and the drug lab. Does it still choose 3 from the other options, the garage, darkroom, etc., or does it only get the special Angel parts and those count as its 3 prechosen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not explicitly answered in the playbooks, but fiction always comes first in Apocalypse World. As the workshop is described in-fiction as an Infirmary, it is specialized for that particular purpose and contains no other components.

Comment: Given that the Savvyhead options for the workspace generally only make sense for a Savvyhead, plus the fact that skilled labor overlaps with what the Angel advancement supplies, I'm inclined to agree with this.  Of course, you can always converse with the MC to establish other fictional elements in your workspace, just be careful what you wish for.

Answer (score 3):

> ***Infirmary***: you get an infirmary, a workspace with life support, a drug lab and a crew of 2 (Shigusa & Mox, maybe). Get patients into it and you can work on them like a savvyhead on tech (*cf*).

I would just claim exactly what it says. Three reasons:

1. In the fiction, the thing you have is an infirmary, which is specifically a hospital-like workspace for working on people, not a garage or a signal-processing console or any other kind of thing.
2. The rules already spell out additional details, like how you get a nice little drug lab and some helpers (p.s. you can rename the helpers, if you want) to go with it. Nice!
3. The game text uses "*cf*" to mean "go look it up." Note how it's only applied to the second sentence, about how to use the infirmary. That's a small thing, I know, but it hints at the author's intent a bit.

If you said you had a gigantic old-school x-ray machine in there, I'd totally let you count it as a dark room later, though.